# Spring JPA : JPQL query returning null value

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA...I am getting a null value from this JPQL query. I am trying to get all the ExamName column data but it is returning a null value..

ExamRepository interface:

```
    @Repository
    public interface ExamRepository extends JpaRepository<ExamEntity,Integer>
    {
        
      @Query("SELECT  e.ExamName from ExamEntity e")
      public List<ExamEntity> getExams();
    
    }
    

ExamEntity class: 
@Entity
@Table(name="exams")
public class ExamEntity {
     
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(length =100)
     private int id;
     
     @Column(nullable=false,length =100)
     private String ExamName;
     
     
     @Column(nullable=false,length =100)
     private String ExamDate;
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your selection and return value. You need to return a list of strings if your selecting the exam names or select the entity.

```
  @Query("SELECT  e.ExamName from ExamEntity e")
  public List<String> getExams();
```

or

```
  // This is redundant however as JpaRepository has findAll()
  @Query("SELECT  e from ExamEntity e")
  public List<ExamEntity> getExams();
```

Comment: I tried String type but still, it is returning null..and  I want only data of ExamName only